# html POST request login to website

Tags: html, post, authentication

Hi im trying to figure out how to login to a website using a post request.
I want to do this because i want to make a web app using particular data from content shown on the website after login.

However i cannot seem to figure out which url i need to use to login.

This is the FORM :

```
<FORM onSubmit="return checkrequired(this)" METHOD=POST ACTION="/pkmslogin.form">
<FONT SIZE="+2">
<TABLE BORDER="0" WIDTH="400">
<TR>
<TD ALIGN="LEFT"><UL><LI>Gebruikersnaam</LI></UL></TD>
<TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="username" SIZE="15" AUTOCOMPLETE="off">
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN="LEFT"><UL><LI>Wachtwoord</LI></UL></TD>
<TD><INPUT TYPE="PASSWORD" NAME="password" SIZE="15" AUTOCOMPLETE="off"></TD>
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="login-form-type" VALUE="pwd">
</TR>
</TABLE>
</FONT>
<BR>&nbsp <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Aanmelden">
```

The javascript checkrequired():

```
function checkrequired(which) {

var pass=true;
if (document.images) {
   for (i=0;i<which.length;i++) {
      var tempobj=which.elements[i];
      if (((tempobj.type=="text"||tempobj.type=="password")&&tempobj.value=='')||(tempobj.type.toString().charAt(0)=="s"&&tempobj.selectedIndex==0)) {
         pass=false;
         break;
      }
   }
}
if (!pass) {
   shortFieldName=tempobj.name.substring(0,30).toUpperCase();
   if (shortFieldName=="USERNAME") {
      shortFieldName="Gebruikersnaam";
   }
   if (shortFieldName=="PASSWORD") {
      shortFieldName="Wachtwoord";
   }
   alert("Het veld \""+shortFieldName+"\" is niet ingevuld.");
   return false;
}
else
   return true;
}
```

I thought i needed to use /?Username='...'&password='...' but this is not the case.

**edit**

---

Chrome developer tools tells me no variables are being passed to the pkmslogin.form

- **Path   =** pkmslogin.form
- **method =** POST
- **Status =** 302    Moved Temporarily
- **type =** text/html
- **Initiator =** Other
- **Size =** 713 B    0 B
- **Time =** 367 ms    366 ms

Comment: Use Ajax : http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Comment: Never use `/?` in a query string. Use `?` --> query string. Make sure that your query arguments match the post arguments in your login script. This is case-sensitive. When the submit button is hit, the browser should post this to `/pkmslogin.form` with `username` and `password` as values.

Comment: Please use a SHA1-script to encrypt the password before you post it to the server. http://phpjs.org/functions/sha1/

Comment: @Mouser trying to reach the url /pkmslogin.form?username='..'&password='..' stops me on the same page

Comment: Edited to show the chrome developer tools feedback

Comment: what kind of page is `.form`?

Comment: Also current html conventions strongly suggest the use of lowercase in html.

Comment: @Mouser I have no acces to the webpage to see what code is on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67747/discussion-between-mouser-and-brian).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using IBM `WebSEAL` but instead of using its management page, you made your own

So, the problem is that you are sending the request to `/pkmslogin.form` but as your application is behind `WebSEAL`, so it must be accessed by a junction.

**So, your request actually goes to:**
https://WebSEAL_HOST:WebSEAL_Instance_Port/Your_Junction/Your_App_Context_Root/pkmslogin.form

You have two solution:

1. Use a relative URL: 
   ../../Your_Junction/pkmslogin.form
2. Use an absolute URL: https://WebSEAL_HOST:WebSEAL_Instance_Port/pkmslogin.form